# Need to disable loop for inline Fancybox gallery - loop: false and cyclic: false not working

Tags: javascript, loops, fancybox, fancybox-2, cyclic

First time posting here, so be kind. I've looked everywhere and can't find my exact issue. I've created a fancybox gallery with inline HTML. It works great on the first click-through, but when it loops back around to the first div, it starts displaying them out of order. Because of this, I'd like to simply disable looping. However, I've tried disabling it through the Javascript to no avail.

For the record, this is the pattern the gallery takes on when navigating through:

- Div 1
- Div 2
- Div 3
- Div 4
- Loops to Div 1
- Div 3
- Div 2
- Div 4
- Div 3
- Div 1

^ If anyone can tell me why this is happening, go for it! It would be greatly appreciated. But I'll be content if I can just get it to stop looping

I'll share some of my code...

The HTML Markup:

```
<div id="container">
<div><p>
    <a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="images/zacthumb.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="#inline2" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="images/zacthumb.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="#inline3" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="images/zacthumb.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="#inline4" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="images/zacthumb.png" alt="" /></a>
</p></div>
</div></div>
<div id="inline1" style="width:820px;display: none;">
    <p id="zac"><font size="4">    
    <b>ZAC NORRIS</b></font><br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing     
elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque. Nulla sit amet sem sapien.   
Vestibulum imperdiet porta ante ac ornare. Nulla et lorem eu nibh adipiscing ultricies nec     at lacus. Cras laoreet ultricies sem, at blandit mi eleifend aliquam. Nunc enim ipsum,     vehicula non pretium varius, cursus ac tortor. Vivamus fringilla congue laoreet. Quisque     ultrices sodales orci, quis rhoncus justo auctor in. Phasellus dui eros, bibendum eu feugiat     ornare, faucibus eu.<br /><br />Nunc aliquet tempus sem, id aliquam diam varius ac. Maecenas     nisl nunc, molestie vitae eleifend vel, iaculis sed magna. Aenean tempus lacus vitae orci    posuere porttitor eget non felis. Donec lectus elit, aliquam nec eleifend sit amet, vestibulum    sed nunc.</p>
    </p><br /><div id="boxnav"><center>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="fancybox" href="#inline2" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="next1.png" onclick="$("ul li a").click(function() { $("#us").toggle("fast"); });"/></a></center></div>
</div>

<div id="inline2" style="width:820px;display: none;">
<p id="zac"><font size="4"><b>PERSON TWO</b></font><br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque. Nulla sit amet sem sapien. Vestibulum imperdiet porta ante ac ornare. Nulla et lorem eu nibh adipiscing ultricies nec at lacus. Cras laoreet ultricies sem, at blandit mi eleifend aliquam. Nunc enim ipsum, vehicula non pretium varius, cursus ac tortor. Vivamus fringilla congue laoreet. Quisque ultrices sodales orci, quis rhoncus justo auctor in. Phasellus dui eros, bibendum eu feugiat ornare, faucibus eu.<br /><br />Nunc aliquet tempus sem, id aliquam diam varius ac. Maecenas nisl nunc, molestie vitae eleifend vel, iaculis sed magna. Aenean tempus lacus vitae orci posuere porttitor eget non felis. Donec lectus elit, aliquam nec eleifend sit amet, vestibulum sed nunc.</p>
    </p><br /><div id="boxnav"><center><a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="prev1.png" onclick="$("ul li a").click(function() { $("#us").toggle("fast"); });"/></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="fancybox" href="#inline3" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="next1.png" onclick="$("ul li a").click(function() { $("#us").toggle("fast"); });"/></a></center></div>
</div>


<div id="inline3" style="width:820px;display: none;">
    <p id="zac"><font size="4"><b>PERSON THREE</b></font><br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque. Nulla sit amet sem sapien. Vestibulum imperdiet porta ante ac ornare. Nulla et lorem eu nibh adipiscing ultricies nec at lacus. Cras laoreet ultricies sem, at blandit mi eleifend aliquam. Nunc enim ipsum, vehicula non pretium varius, cursus ac tortor. Vivamus fringilla congue laoreet. Quisque ultrices sodales orci, quis rhoncus justo auctor in. Phasellus dui eros, bibendum eu feugiat ornare, faucibus eu.<br /><br />Nunc aliquet tempus sem, id aliquam diam varius ac. Maecenas nisl nunc, molestie vitae eleifend vel, iaculis sed magna. Aenean tempus lacus vitae orci posuere porttitor eget non felis. Donec lectus elit, aliquam nec eleifend sit amet, vestibulum sed nunc.</p>
    </p><br /><div id="boxnav"><center><a class="fancybox" href="#inline2" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="prev1.png" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="fancybox" href="#inline4" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="next1.png" /></a></center></div>
</div>


<div id="inline4" style="width:820px;display: none;">
    <p id="zac"><font size="4"><b>PERSON FOUR</b></font><br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque. Nulla sit amet sem sapien. Vestibulum imperdiet porta ante ac ornare. Nulla et lorem eu nibh adipiscing ultricies nec at lacus. Cras laoreet ultricies sem, at blandit mi eleifend aliquam. Nunc enim ipsum, vehicula non pretium varius, cursus ac tortor. Vivamus fringilla congue laoreet. Quisque ultrices sodales orci, quis rhoncus justo auctor in. Phasellus dui eros, bibendum eu feugiat ornare, faucibus eu.<br /><br />Nunc aliquet tempus sem, id aliquam diam varius ac. Maecenas nisl nunc, molestie vitae eleifend vel, iaculis sed magna. Aenean tempus lacus vitae orci posuere porttitor eget non felis. Donec lectus elit, aliquam nec eleifend sit amet, vestibulum sed nunc.</p>
    </p><br /><div id="boxnav"><center><a class="fancybox" href="#inline3" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="prev1.png" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</center></div>
</div>
```

The failing Javascript? Can provide more if needed:

```
    defaults: {
        padding : 5,
        margin  : 20,

        width     : 800,
        height    : 600,
        minWidth  : 100,
        minHeight : 100,
        maxWidth  : 9999,
        maxHeight : 9999,

        autoSize   : true,
        autoHeight : false,
        autoWidth  : false,

        autoResize  : true,
        autoCenter  : !isTouch,
        fitToView   : true,
        aspectRatio : false,
        topRatio    : 0.5,
        leftRatio   : 0.5,

        scrolling : 'auto', // 'auto', 'yes' or 'no'
        wrapCSS   : '',

        arrows     : true,
        closeBtn   : true,
        closeClick : false,
        nextClick  : false,
        mouseWheel : false,
        autoPlay   : false,
        playSpeed  : 3000,
        preload    : 3,
        modal      : false,
        cyclic       : false,
```

Thank you in advance.

<3 Laura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this one is easy to explain :

Fancybox will create a gallery out of ALL `<a>` tags with `class="fancybox"` AND `data-fancybox-group="gallery"` ... including those **INSIDE** your inline(s) content.

In other words, if have your thumbnails like :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline2" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="2_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline3" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="3_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline4" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="4_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

... then the fancybox gallery will consist of 4 elements in that order, **however**, if you also include inside the content of `#inline1` :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline2" data-fancybox-group="gallery">Fog >></a>
```

...  then you are adding a *fifth* element to your gallery (`#inline2`) and this is why `#inline2` is always displayed after the `#inline4`

Of course, if you add inside `#inline2`

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><< Trees</a> | 
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline3" data-fancybox-group="gallery">Sunshine >></a>
```

... then `#inline1` becomes the *6th* element of your gallery AND `#inline3` the `7th`, and so on and so forth.

At this point your gallery will be

- #inline1
- #inline2
- #inline3
- #inline4
- #inline2
- #inline1
- #inline3
  etc.

How can you solve it?

If you want to include your own navigation inside your inline content(s), first consider how javascript indexes work, where the *first* element starts with `index = 0`  so :

- trees = 0
- fog = 1
- sunshine = 2
- paris = 3

If you know the index of each element of the gallery you want to move to, then you could use the fancybox method `$.fancybox.jumpto()` to navigate through the gallery.

So, if you want to go to *fog* (from within `#inline1`), instead of this :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline2" data-fancybox-group="gallery">Fog >></a>
```

...  do this :

```
<a href="javascript:$.fancybox.jumpto(1);">Fog &gt;&gt;</a>
```

**NOTICE** that I am escaping the character `>` using its form `&gt;` to avoid html validation errors (use `&lt;` for the character `<` instead)

Comment: WOW! You are a complete and total life saver. Thank you SO MUCH. :) This worked perfectly. My lack of knowledge of Javascript really bit me here. THANK YOU AGAIN. <3

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple onclick attributes written like this

```
onclick="$("ul li a").click(function() { $("#us").toggle("fast"); });"
```

in your code, which is wrong - this attribute contains just the $ sign because of your incorrect handling of quotes. Fix that first, and see if the problem persists. And if so, please provide at least an online example.

Comment: I'm sorry... I really appreciate your response! But I'm not familiar with JS at all, and I'm not sure how you're suggesting I fix this. What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: And this isn't the exact online example, but an earlier iteration. The relevant parts of the code should be the same though (under "the designers") http://www.laurakcole.com/ss/demo/index.html